# How can you indent about this mixed situation?

Tags: php, html, coding-style, indentation

Here is my code mixed PHP and HTML.
(It shows 4X4 table.)

How can u make this code to get more readability?

If u change HTML indentation, U should change whole HTML.
(This code is part of whole source.)

Do u have any idea for me. Please let me know. Ta.

```
<!-- GALLERY BEGIN -->
<tr>
  <td style="padding-top:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <?php
      $ii = 0;
      $aRows = getArticle('board_table', $DB_CONNECT, 8);
      foreach ($aRows as $iidx => $aRow) :
          $ii++;
          $U = getUpfiles('upload_table',$aRow[uid],'');
          $pic = getImage($U);
      ?>
      <td width="75"><table width="60" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><a href="<?=$aRow[link]?>"><img src="<?=$pic?>"/></a></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><?=getStrCut($aRow[subject], 8, '..')?></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
          <?php if($ii%4==0): ?>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>    
          <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
<!-- END BEGIN -->
```

Comment: I would start by using braces ({}) for your loops instead of BASIC-like syntax. This will make it easier to read and indent (IMO). Also I would recommend extra spacing between code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some kind of templating engine. Like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net). That will allow you to keep your design en data more seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even bother about the HTML indentation, it doesn't matter the least bit. Neither to your users, nor to your browser and for your debugging, you should use something like the Developer Tools from Chrome or good ol' Firebug - Those tools indent your HTML for you, no matter what the actual codebase looks like.

Indent the way you can read the code best, and not what you think is best for the program. As for that, you should really avoid mixing HTML and PHP at all. As bkwint already said, use templating engines like SMARTY or TWIG. Although, with them you still have some weird "in-between" code in your HTML, but it will look much cleaner and easier to understand.

As for your current code: Go with the standard indentation, no matter if you are in a PHP code block or in the HTML parts. That means, indent when opening a loop, an if or a tag. This should at least somehow clean up that table-driven-madness you have going there.